# JQuery and the editableSelect package is not allowing me to Filter a select menu with a RegExp. JavaScript and jQuery nub or novice

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Here is a select list built using PHP, MariaDB, and HTML:

```
    echo "<select name='companylist' id='companylist' size='86' value='' tabindex='1' >";
    echo "<option value=''></option>";
    echo "<option value='0-Create a New Company'>0-Create a New Company</option>";
    foreach ($companyResult as $company) {
      echo "<option id='".$company['Company_Key']."' 
      value='".$company['Company_Key']."'>".$company['Company_Names']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

It builds a dropdown list that is appropriate for my application.

Next, I built this testing script to find out if I was on the right track in the use of RegExp to filter the dropdown select list dynamically, and it works well, for its purpose.  I only built it because the list following it is giving me fits.

```
    echo "<script>";
    echo "$('#companylist option').each(function() {
           var Val = this.text;
           var Filter='W';
           var CompRegex = new RegExp('^'+Filter);
           if(CompRegex.test(Val)){
             console.log('RegExp with Filter has found the following Val starting with this 
             Filter: '+Filter);
             console.log('Val = ' + Val);
           }
         })";
    echo "</script>";
```

This above gives me the following console output:
RegExp with Filter has found the following Val starting with this Filter: W
Val = Welch Tile
RegExp with Filter has found the following Val starting with this Filter: W
Val = West Michigan Molding
RegExp with Filter has found the following Val starting with this Filter: W
Val = WL Molding of MI
This is a good start.

```
    echo "<script>";
    echo "  $('#companylist')";
    echo "    .editableSelect()";
    echo "    .on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
                 console.log('value = ' + document.getElementById('companylist').value);
                 console.log('li.val() = '+li.val());
                 getCustomer_Names(li.val());
                 getTool_Numbers(li.val());
                 getPart_Name(li.val());
                 newCompany_Name();
               })";
    echo "</script>";
```

This above script loads other menus, as expected, once the user selects an item.

The next script here simply will not let me get the option text that the user sees in the list.  I have 5 days into this, because I am new to JQuery and not a master of Javascript either, but I do read all kinds of sites for help, including reference guides, and the support boards (thank you for this one!), but I would like a happy ending soon.  Any help, as stated, would be very appreciated.

```
    echo "<script>";
    echo "  $('#companylist')";
    echo "    .editableSelect()";
    echo "    .on('input.editable-select', function () {
                 $(this).each(function() {
                   var Val = this.text;
                   var Filter = this.value;
                   var CompRegExp = new RegExp('^'+Filter);
                   console.log('Val = '+Val);
                   console.log('Filter = '+Filter);
                   console.log('CompRegExp = '+CompRegExp);
                   if(CompRegExp.test(Val)){
                     console.log('RegExp with Filter has found the following Val starting with this 
                     Filter: '+Filter);
                     console.log('Val = ' + Val);
                   }
                   else {
                     // remove from select list
                   }
                 });
               });";
    echo "</script>";
```

This above script gives me

```
Val = undefined
Filter = a
CompRegExp = /^a/
```

It is the "Val = undefined" that is my undoing.

I also took a long-view of this problem and wrote a jQuery/JavaScript program that clears the dropdown list and then recreates the options by having a PHP program re-query the database to get the values that match a SQL LIKE 'Input%' which I will include to show you the depth of effort here.  The problem here is that I could not get the dropdown menu to stay open even though I issued .editableSelect('show'); as instructed in the editableSelect git website to open the dropdown menu and show the modified list, although, if I clicked in the field and moved the cursor around, it would pop the menu open with the values that matched the return from MariaDB.  It follows:

```
    echo "<script>
      function getCompany_Names(comp_val)
      {
          if(document.getElementById('companylist').value.substring(0,8) != '0-Create'){
          $('#companylist').editableSelect('clear');
          var xhttp;
          if (comp_val === null || comp_val === '' ) {
            $('#companylist').editableSelect('add', '<option value=></option>');
            $('#companylist').editableSelect('add', '<option value=0-Create a New Company>0-Create a 
               New Company</option>');
          }
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              var select = $('#companylist');
              var c_text = this.responseText;
              console.log('comp_ctext = ' + c_text);
              c_text = JSON.parse(c_text);
    
              $.each($(c_text),function(key,value){
                if (value.compname == 'One or more Company Names are Probably Not Entered.')
                {
                  $('#companylist').editableSelect('add','<option value=' + 'One or more Company 
                  Names are Probably Not Entered.' + '>One or more Company Names are Probably Not 
                  Entered.</option>');
                }
                else
                {
                  console.log('<option id=\'' + value.compkey + '\' value=\'' + value.compkey + '\'>' 
                  + value.compname + '</option>');
                  $('#companylist').editableSelect('add','<option id=\'' + value.compkey + '\' 
                  value=\'' + value.compkey + '\'>' + value.compname + '</option>');
                }
              }); // end .editableSelect('add',...)
            }
          };
          xhttp.open('GET', 'getCompany_Names.php?q='+comp_val, true);
          xhttp.send();
         }
        }
    
        </script>";
```

This is all because my patron does not like the default filter behavior of the editableSelect package where it matches what is typed to any values anywhere in the dropdown and wants some dropdowns to come up matching the input to the results from first character onward with something like (exactly like) a regex of `/^input_variable/`.

Thank you for your time.

R

Comment: I want to add that I don't know how to get the option text that the user sees to do a RegExp on with their typed input with the above code within the confines of the editableSelect package.  I am going to have to do this project off hours on my time if I cannot get there soon.  I realize I need to know more.  Thank you...

Comment: what is **.editableSelect()**?

Comment: and could you show the html linked with **input.editable-select**

Comment: It turns a regular HTML <select> menu into an menu with an input box which can be used to dynamically add and remove items from the list, as well as manage the list with a few custom abilities.  See-> https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/jquery-editable-select

Comment: The HTML is already in the code list above.  It is just disguised by PHP.  It is the first code posted in this request.  The options listed get their values from a PHP program that grabs its values from a MariaDB database.  This does not appear to be the problem (and I have multiple years doing them, so okay there, I think).  P.Izze

Comment: Here is a subtext of an actual retrieve from our database:  <select name='companylist' id='companylist' size='86' value='' tabindex='1' ><option value=''></option><option value='0-Create a New Company'>0-Create a New Company</option><option id='5' value='5'>2E Fabricating, LLC</option><option id='3' value='3'>2K Tool</option></select>

Comment: i dont see this event in the documentation: **input.editable-select**

Comment: input is a jQuery event.  The editable-select is similar to the select event and, without it (I have tried), it breaks that section of the code.  If I type something in the input box that the editableSelect package provides, I can and do retrieve its value(s) and can console.log them.  I just cannot get the option value that the user sees (like 2E Fabricating if they enter a 2...)

Comment: i dont understant this syntax  **.on('input.editable-select', function ()**, there is no selector before .on?

Answer (score 0):

its not a solution, just easier to ask something..i'll delete more later

i dont understand this syntax: no selector before .on??

```
.on('input.editable-select', function () {
                 $(this).each(function() {
```

i see $(this) that means you have more input?

the problem with these lines:

```
               var Val = this.text;
               var Filter = this.value;
```

what is `Val`?  because `this.text` is not functional for input?  (its the reason Val  => undefined)

`this.value` gives what you type in input

Comment: Okay, I did know that Val was not the this.value.  If I do a $('#companylist option').each(function() { var Val = this.text; console.log(Val) }); I get all the options the user would see.  But when I put it $('#companylist').editableSelect().on('input.editable-select', function () { $('#companylist option').each(function() { var CVal = this.text; console.log ('CVal = '+CVal); }),  I get an undefined.  It enters the loop, but the same code without the the .editableSelect().on event works fine.  Any thoughts?  I admit my newness to jQuery and this and $(this) are foggy at this point.

Comment: so i dont understand what does this part of code, why you have an  each loop..

Comment: I look at each option, and then compare it to the input (hence the identifier .on(input.editable-select) and compare each option with a RegExp(/'^'+Filter/) where Filter=this.value.   This is the basic pattern of the first testing script above.  I am gather the input with every key-punch and assigning it to Filter and doing the same tests at the first test but my options are not showing up in this.text.  I realize that the $('#companylist') does not have a "option' in it, as $('#companylist option') is not in the .on(input...), but if added, the script fails.  If you have time to try it out.

Comment: *this.val* is what you type  , do you want to select all options which begins by this.val? so what attribute of option?

Answer (score 0):

This is WAY more complicated than my core problem actually is.  I have posted another question that is just my actual failure.  It is at: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801231/the-use-of-https-github-com-indrimuska-jquery-editable-select-for-editable-sel]

I think I have an example of an example page the creator put together and it has a function their I am only just starting to understand, but it is all about adding values to the list.  I will study it and post my results on the core issue page.  Thank you to all who tried to help.  Here's one for brevity.